# Prove that entropy is maximized when probability is $1/n$

Tags: computer-science, entropy

How can be proven that the entropy of a dice roll is maximized when the probability of each of its $6$ faces is equal, $1/6$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suprise is defined as -log(p{X=x}). A good way to think of entropy is the "expected surprise". In this sense, its easy to see that the uniform distribution maximizes the expected surprise.

Comment: not sure how to do it... can you help?

Answer (score 1):

The entropy is given by $-\sum p_i\ln p_i$. Use [Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) with the logarithm function.

Comment: not sure how to do it... can you help?